# How to deduce Künneth from its relative version (in cohomology of sheaves)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, sheaf-theory

Let $p:X\to S$ and $q:Y\to S$ be morphisms of "spaces" over $S$. We have an isomorphism
$$f_!(M\boxtimes N)=p_! M\otimes q_!N$$
in the derived category of "sheaves" over $S$, where $f:X\times_S Y\to S$ is the natural map. This holds for locally compact Hausdorff topological spaces (and abelian sheaves) and for certain schemes (and $\mathscr{O}$-modules), where in the latter we have $f_!=f_*$. We can see this as a somewhat relative version of the Künneth formula.

**I wonder how we can deduce from this a more usual Künneth formula such as**
$$H^i_c(X\times_S Y,M\boxtimes N)=\bigoplus_{j+k=i} H_c^j(X,M)\otimes H_c^k(Y,N).$$
Of course, I don't expect this to hold in extreme generality, so feel free to assume (if needed) that $S$ is a point (or the spectrum of a field, in the case of schemes).

Possible idea: we have that $H^i_c(X\times_S Y,M\boxtimes N)=\hom_{\mathsf{D}(S)}(\mathscr{O}_S,f_!(M\boxtimes N)[i])=\hom_{\mathsf{D}(S)}(\mathscr{O}_S,p_! M\otimes q_! N[i])$. So it suffices to show that

$$\hom_{\mathsf{D}(S)}(\mathscr{O}_S,p_! M\otimes q_! N[i])=\bigoplus_{j+k=i} \hom_{\mathsf{D}(S)}(\mathscr{O}_S,p_! M[j])\otimes \hom_{\mathsf{D}(S)}(\mathscr{O}_S,q_! N[k]),$$
which seems like a purely categorical statement.

Comment: The latter statement (and the "more usual" Künneth formula) is unfortunately false, unless $M,N$ are sheaves of $k$-modules for a field $k$. Indeed you can see that even for $M=N=\mathbb{Z}$ the [usual formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%BCnneth_theorem#Singular_homology_with_coefficients_in_a_principal_ideal_domain) has also a Tor term.

Comment: @DenisNardin Indeed. That's why I've said that we can assume $S$ to be $\operatorname{Spec}k$ for a field $k$. (But I've forgot to say that we can suppose $S$ to be the ringed space $(\text{pt},\underline{k})$ in the topological case.) So... assuming that, how can we deduce the "more usual Künneth formula" from its relative version?

Comment: In that case, the claim is that $H_*(C\otimes_k D) \cong H_*(C)\otimes_k H_*(D)$, for $C,D$ complexes of $k$-vector spaces, which is the classical Künneth theorem from homological algebra. You can prove it for example by observing that in $D(k)$, every object is equivalent to a sum of shifts of the trivial module $k$, so you can reduce to that case.

Comment: The following might be relevant:
http://rvirk.com/incomplete/kunneth.pdf
(Note: I am virtually positive that the author has every functor involved implicitly derived).

Comment: I'm not sure I exactly understand the scope of your question (what kind of sheaves), but for étale constructible sheaves an idea would be to deduce your formula by working stalkwise, i.e., apply $i^*$ for $i : \{s\} \to S$ running over all geometric points. $i^*$ is monoidal and commutes with lower-!-functors (base change), and the collection of all $i^*$ is conservative. In the case where $S = \{s\}$ your formula is the more "usual" Künneth formula as displayed.

Comment: @AchimKrause could you explain a little more? I understand that in $D(k)$ every object is equivalent to a sum of shifts of $k$ but not how we finish the proof.

Comment: @Jakob my context is precisely the following: I want to see which properties of cohomology follow simply by having a six functor formalism. So I consider an arbitrary category $C$ of "spaces" and triangulated rigid tensor categories $D(X)$ for each $X\in C$, along with pairs of adjunct functors $f^*\dashv f_*$, $f_!\dashv f^!$, with $f^*$ monoidal. I also suppose proper base change and a projection formula. Then I "define" $H^i(X,M)$ as $\hom_{\mathsf{D}(S)}(\mathcal{O}_S,p_* M[i])$, where $p:X\to S$ is the natural map to a final object $S$ of $C$ (whose existence is supposed).

Comment: @Gabriel: OK, then I think the axiomatics I suggested should work. Related to your idea that this is a "purely categorical statement" you were asking about: I have a feeling that if your category $D(S)$ is compactly generated by dualizable objects (as is the case for $D(S)$ being the category of quasi-coherent sheaves on a scheme), then this statement looks reasonable: reduce to both $p_*M$ and $q_*N$ being dualizable, then $Hom(1, A^\vee) = Hom(A, 1)$ etc.